# how to avoid getting the last row id when using submit method PHP delete

Tags: php, html

I'm using POST method to delete the record data

assume I have 3 data

A B C of id 1 2 3 .

A Delete

B Delete

C Delete

If I'm clicking B or A to delete mean that B is not deleted C is getting deleted.  BCZ its selecting last row id. I don't want that I want to delete the selected row.

MY code

```
<?php foreach ($userdetails as $key => $userdetail): ?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $userdetail['Name']; ?></td>
<td>
<input type="hidden" name="delete-id" value="<?php echo $userdetail['id']; ?>">
                                            
<button type="submit" name="single-delete" class="btn btn-trash-alt">
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
</button>
</td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['single-delete'])){
    $delete_id = $_POST['delete-id'];
    userdelete($delete_id);
}

function userdelete($delete_id){
    
    global $db;

    if(mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM users WHERE id =$delete_id")){
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Data deleted successfully";
    }else{
        $_SESSION['success'] ="Something went wrong, Try again";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: if I use url method to delete data mean its working  like index.php?delete-id=<?php echo $userdetail['id']; ?> But with this method my url become dirty. so how can i achive with above method

Comment: okay,I'm new to PHP, ill try to  do my code better. Now what's the mistake i did? pls crct me

Comment: I don't see any `<form>` tag, how are you submit the request? Are you wrapping the whole table with `<form>` tag? Or you are using AJAX?

Comment: If you are wrapping the whole table with a form tag, all of your hidden input has the same name `delete-id` and when you submit the form, it only send the last value.

Comment: <form name="multipledeletion" method="post"></form> ya whole table

Comment: so what to do im using input tags in multiple places inside the table

Comment: You could create a separate form for each of the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot wrong here. I'm assuming this is an admin operation not open to users? If this is not the case you need to identify users with a login cookie and read that cookie to make sure they have authority to delete their id and not anyone elses!

Info on why the last row id is being selected may be because you are displaying an array of id's and you need to run a foreach loop to get the value of the button clicked.

First get the post data & sanitize it.

```
 if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
 $ids = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['id']); // $ids - Pluralized on purpose...
 }
```

To further prevent tampering, now search for this id in your table to check if it exists, we are also making sure the actual button clicked corresponds to its assigned value;

```
 foreach ($ids as $id) {
 $select = mysqli_query($db,"select id from mytable where id='$id'");
 }
```

Now check that the id matches a single result...

```
 if (mysqli_num_rows($select)==1) {
```

Retrieve the singular result...

```
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
 $real_id = $row['id'];
 }
```

Finally delete the id using a prepared statement...

```
 $delete = mysqli_prepare($db, "delete from mytable where id=?");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($delete, "s", $real_id);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($delete);
 }

 } // closing the if statement for num rows
```

Notes: operation is now protected for admin use, not for public access.